# Existence of a beforeSave on User causes authData to be missing in afterSave of User

Tags: parse-platform

I have an afterSave method that takes the authData from a user signing up with Facebook and retrieves his friends. This has been working fine until I later defined a beforeSave method on the User, the authData was no longer present in the afterSave method. Example code below:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function (request, response){
    response.success();
});
```

Even though that method doesn't do anything, it prevents authData from being present in the afterSave from the same chain:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

var user = request.object;
user.fetch();

if (!user.existed()) {  
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url:'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token='+user.get('authData').facebook.access_token,
        success:function(httpResponse){
            // process user friends
        },
        error:function(httpResponse){
            console.error(httpResponse);
        }
    });

    }
});
```

i have used

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

and

```
user.fetch();
```

still got the following error in the log

```
Result: TypeError: Cannot read property 'facebook' of undefined
```

Comment: Please open this as an official bug report on developers.facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be careful as `fetch()` is an async call, so should be chained:

```
user.fetch().then(function (user) {
    // now have access to updated user
});
```

In your code your fetch will have no effect on the code after it, since you're not waiting for it to finish.